# Spring Boot 2 - JPA + Pagable problem on ManyToMany tables

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-boot-jpa

In Spring Boot 2 JPA, I have the following two many to many Entities.

1- Labor:

```
@Entity
public class Labor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String mobile;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private boolean male;
    private boolean active;
    private String brife;
    @Column(length = 500)
    private String specifcation;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "labor_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "labor_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and Tag table:

```
@Entity
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(length = 100, unique = true)
    private String name;
    private boolean active = true;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tags")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Labor> labors = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Then I defined Labor Repository to query Labors with certain Tag ID ,gender, or ages

```
@Repository
public interface LaborReoistory extends JpaRepository<Labor, Long> {

    @Query("select l from Labor l join l.tags t where (:tid is null or t.id in :tid) and " +
            "(:isMale is null or :isMale = TRUE) and " +
            "((:startYear is null or :endYear is null or :startYear >  :endYear) or year(l.dateOfBirth) >= :startYear and year(l.dateOfBirth) <= :endYear)")
    Page<Labor> findLaborsByCondition(@Param("tid") final long[] tid,
                                      @Param("isMale") final Boolean isMale,
                                      @Param("startYear") final Integer startYear,
                                      @Param("endYear") final Integer endYear,
                                      final Pageable pageable);

}
```

When I use this repository in my controller, I find the **totalElements** property of the Pagable returned counts to records in **labor_tag**(in this case 16 records),but what I actually want is to have **totalElements**  count on Labors with given conditions. does JPA Pagable support such query or how can I find a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any duplicate labors in Page response ?

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks no, when I ran this query without Paging it returned actual labor set with multiple tags and actual labor number in the table

Comment: It seems there should be duplicate labor then you should use `select distinct l ...`  I think

Comment: I mean if `totalElements` is return 16 then must be you query will return 16 row after joining thats  why therer is possibility of duplicate Labor for joining

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks I tried distinct as you suggested. it worked. thanks. please provide solution to this question so it could be saved as solution. thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After joining there will be duplicate `Labor` but `totalElements` is the count of total number of row using the query. So you should use `Distinct` on `Labour` to get the count of distinct Labour

```
@Query("select distinct l from Labor l join l.tags t where (:tid is null or t.id in :tid) and " +
            "(:isMale is null or :isMale = TRUE) and " +
            "((:startYear is null or :endYear is null or :startYear >  :endYear) or year(l.dateOfBirth) >= :startYear and year(l.dateOfBirth) <= :endYear)")
```